# Why does PIP convert underscores to dashes

Tags: python, pip, pyramid, python-poetry

I am trying to install a Pyramid app -- let's say `test_app`. inside a virtual environment and it is getting installed as `test-app` (pip freeze output shows it `test-app==0.0`).

Because of this, I can not import the package.

How should I fix this problem?

More info:
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2011-August/017935.html

I am using pip version 1.3.1

setup.py:

```
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
README = open(os.path.join(here, 'README.txt')).read()
CHANGES = open(os.path.join(here, 'CHANGES.txt')).read()

requires = [
    'pyramid',
    'pyramid_debugtoolbar',
    'waitress',
    ]

setup(name='test_app',
      version='0.0',
      description='test_app',
      long_description=README + '\n\n' + CHANGES,
      classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Framework :: Pyramid",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: WSGI :: Application",
        ],
      author='',
      author_email='',
      url='',
      keywords='web pyramid pylons',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      install_requires=requires,
      tests_require=requires,
      test_suite="test_app",
      entry_points="""\
      [paste.app_factory]
      main = test_app:main
      """,
      )
```

UPDATE:

to summarize the findings so far:

- It is normal that pip reports the package name as test-app.
- It is not normal that the egg link is pointing to your virtual env root.
- But the fact that the .egg-info file is created inside your virtual env root as well points to develop using that directory as the egg root.

**Update 2021**

I have now started using [Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry) instead of pip for all my new Python projects. It works well for both normal projects and Jupyter notebooks. With its better developer experience for package management all I'd have to do for the above example would be

```
poetry run xyz
```

where `xyz` is a script that I define within the spec file (akin to `package.json` for `npm`). I would be able to import my own package as all other packages.

Comment: Summary so far: The `develop` command creates a `.egg-info` directory in the virtual env root, and the `.egg-link` file points to that same root directory. This is the cause of the import error. The fact that `pip` reports the package name as `test-app` is normal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update 2021

Use [Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry) instead of `pip`.

---

Original answer:

So, finally after a lot of fiddling around, I've found the solution -- which is annoyingly simple.

I am using virtualenv and am installing the package in the development mode.

I was installing the package from the wrong location. Turns out that the location (directory) from which you run `python setup.py develop` is indeed the one that goes into the `.egg-link` file.

You should install the package into the virtual environment FROM the location where your code is.

So, for example, let's say your code resides in '/a/b' and your virtualenv env is in '/x/y/env', then you should install the package like this:

```
$ cd /a/b
$ /x/y/env/bin/python setup.py develop
```

This will install the package properly.

Hence, the '-' and '_' issue is not a problem and you should be careful about the location from where you are installing the package in the `develop` mode.

Comment: FWIW, I've taken to using `pip install -e .` instead of `python setup.py develop`. They're functionally equivalent, but pip's version has fewer bugs.

Comment: Why does it have less bugs? Any chance you could provide a link?